# How to show selected options from the data in a dropdown?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting json data from the backend and I want a multiselect dropdown to show defaulted value on the multiselect dropdown from the below data I am getting.I am using React-select's Multi select dropdown

Below is the format of the data that I am getting I want to show as default value from the skill Object.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5dc672b9ff33d00669ba7dec",
        "userSkills": [
            {
                "_id": "5dc672b9ff33d00669ba7def",
                "skill": {
                    "_id": "5dbff84885400a1b1ab99e4b",
                    "skillName": "React"
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dc672b9ff33d00669ba7dee",
                "skill": {
                    "_id": "5dc278798fe4430d32188a1c",
                    "skillName": "Php"
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dc672b9ff33d00669ba7ded",
                "skill": {
                    "_id": "5dbff86f85400a1b1ab99e4e",
                    "skillName": "ExpressJS"
                }
            }
        ],
        "employee": {
            "_id": "5dba9d8b1df3d41104981957",
            "username": "sample1"
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dc9504b8a4bf60f2e1581d8",
        "userSkills": [
            {
                "_id": "5dc9504b8a4bf60f2e1581da",
                "skill": {
                    "_id": "5dbff84885400a1b1ab99e4b",
                    "skillName": "React"
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dc9504b8a4bf60f2e1581d9",
                "skill": {
                    "_id": "5dc278798fe4430d32188a1c",
                    "skillName": "Php"
                }
            }
        ],
        "employee": {
            "_id": "5dbbf74a875d930d317849b9",
            "username": "sample2"
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: See [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Comment: Which values do you want to show in dropdown. ie. whether employee id and username or userskills list? Can you be more specific

Comment: i want to show userskills list @swapnil2993

Comment: What did u try?

Comment: I tried to do forEach to the data coming from the api and pushed into the array for which the first data has 3 elements and the second has 2 elements

Comment: Create an array and merge all the data and then using array map create {label: '', value:''} object

Comment: @Biswajeetgope check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58813372/6544460 and let me know if you need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `react-select`

yarn add react-select

```
const data = [
  {
    _id: "5dc672b9ff33d00669ba7dec",
    userSkills: [
      {
        _id: "5dc672b9ff33d00669ba7def",
        skill: {
          _id: "5dbff84885400a1b1ab99e4b",
          skillName: "React"
        }
      },
      {
        _id: "5dc672b9ff33d00669ba7dee",
        skill: {
          _id: "5dc278798fe4430d32188a1c",
          skillName: "Php"
        }
      },
      {
        _id: "5dc672b9ff33d00669ba7ded",
        skill: {
          _id: "5dbff86f85400a1b1ab99e4e",
          skillName: "ExpressJS"
        }
      }
    ],
    employee: {
      _id: "5dba9d8b1df3d41104981957",
      username: "sample1"
    },
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5dc9504b8a4bf60f2e1581d8",
    userSkills: [
      {
        _id: "5dc9504b8a4bf60f2e1581da",
        skill: {
          _id: "5dbff84885400a1b1ab99e4b",
          skillName: "React"
        }
      },
      {
        _id: "5dc9504b8a4bf60f2e1581d9",
        skill: {
          _id: "5dc278798fe4430d32188a1c",
          skillName: "Php"
        }
      }
    ],
    employee: {
      _id: "5dbbf74a875d930d317849b9",
      username: "sample2"
    },
    __v: 0
  }
];
let options = data[0].userSkills.map(skill=> skill?{value:skill.skill.skillName, label:skill.skill.skillName.toUpperCase()}:skill)
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null
  };
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
         onChange={this.handleChange}
          defaultValue={[selectedOption]}
          isMulti
          name="colors"
          options={options}
          className="basic-multi-select"
          classNamePrefix="select"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: output]